# Open Source LMS for nationwide usage

Tags: open-source

I am looking for an open source LMS that can be used for thousands of schools in the country.

Can Moodle, Canvas, TalentLMS be integrated on a country level?

Does it depend on the server or LMS features that millions of users can be supported on a single site?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which meaning of LMS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMS has a few and it is not obvious from your question. How big a country?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please also see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for what details we miss. Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: LMS stands for Learning Management System in context of software such as Moodle... but Steve makes a valid point - It will be helpful to include more specs when asking for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Moodle can easily be integrated at country level and the limitation is usually in how well your underlying infrastructure handles the load - The app itself is pretty solid and will work well for a pretty huge userbase.